# Handsontable table cannot set type to numeric?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am trying to use handsontable to build an editor for my user to add data to my database.

I have the following HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.35.0/handsontable.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.35.0/handsontable.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style='height:100px; width:100px; background-color: black' id='hello'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="stuff.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And stuff.js

```
let colNames = ['adwords_id', 'status', 'client', 'is_unlimited', 'account_budget',
                'remaining_account_budget', 'currency', 'exchange_rate', 'vendor', 'batch',
                'vps', 'login', 'password', 'external_comment', 'internal_comment']

hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('hello'), {
  startRows:8,
  startCols: colNames.length,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: colNames,
  columns: [
    { allowEmpty: false },
    { type:'dropdown', source: ['active', 'dead'] },
    { type:'dropdown', source: ['bart', 'alex'] },
    { type:'checkbox' },
    { type:'numeric',     // TODO undefined "culture"
      numericFormat: { pattern: '$0,0.00', culture: 'en-US' },
    },

    {},
    { type:'dropdown', source: ['usd', 'hkd'] },
    {},
    { type:'dropdown', source: ['acme inc', 'hong kong company'] },
    {},

    { type:'dropdown', source: ['hk-001', 'hk-002'] },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
  ]

});
```

Somehow when I try to edit the column for "account_budget", I am getting the following error:

```
handsontable.min.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'culture' of undefined
    at i (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at i.setDataAtCell (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at Object.populateFromArray (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at i.populateFromArray (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at t.n.saveValue (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at t.n.finishEditing (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at n.closeEditor (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at n.closeEditorAndSaveChanges (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at i.p (handsontable.min.js:29)
    at e.value (handsontable.min.js:29)
```

I turned numeric off and this error is gone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
{
  data: 'price_usd',
  type: 'numeric',
  format: '$0,0.00',
  language: 'en-US' // this is the default locale, set up for USD
},
{
  data: 'price_eur',
  type: 'numeric',
  format: '0,0.00 $',
  language: 'de-DE'
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v8L8wcr/)